# RSA implementation not working with large values for plaintext

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, block-cipher, decryption

While implementing RSA encryption/decryption (using python), the plaintext doesn't match with the decrypted ciphertext for large values of plaintext. Works fine for smaller values for plaintext (numeric value).

> Input: p=53 q=59 e=3  plaintext = 1000 (private key computed as 2011)

Here, the decryption gives `1000` as the plaintext, which is correct.
Now, if

> Input: p=53 q=59 e=3  plaintext = 10000 (private key computed as 2011)

Here, after the decryption, the computed plaintext is `619` (which should be `10000`)

The code for the same is here,

```
    def encrypt(plaintext):
            ciphertext = (plaintext**publicKey) % (self.n)
            return ciphertext
   def decrypt(ciphertext):
            plaintext = (ciphertext**privateKey) % (self.n)
            return plaintext
```

Considering the algorithm will be used to encrypt/decrypt alphanumeric text, which will produce large numeric values, what modifications are needed or am I missing something?

ps: Checking for multiple values of plaintext,it may be happening because `n=3127` and any plaintext greater than `3127` will not produce the original plaintext upon decryption. I might be wrong.

How to make it work for plaintext greater than `n`, here `3127`?

Comment: RSA is a trapdoor permutation! How do you expect to get a plaintext that is larger than the modulus size encrypted and decrypted correctly? The message $m$ must be $m < N$ where $N$ is the modulus and $m$ is the message. Before implementing read at least [Wikipedia RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem))?

Comment: may be a duplicate of [How should I address message size limits in RSA encryption?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/71092/18298)

Comment: $10000 \pmod{53\cdot 51} = 619$ as expected!

Comment: I've answered this more than once I think, but [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/50183/1172) already indicates a way around it for practicing purposes: split your message up and encrypt each piece separately. Beware that you should be able to distinguish separate ciphertext though (i.e. if you cannot distinguish between 5 followed by 23 and 52 followed by 3 then you're in trouble).

Comment: The better way is to use hybrid encryption. Pick a random number between 0 and N. Call that number X. Use a KDF to derive a key from X. Encrypt using an AEAD like ChaCha20-Poly1305. Encrypt X with RSA. Send the encrypted X and the ciphertext of the message (and IV & tag). Recipient can decrypt X, use the same KDF, verify the tag, and decrypt the message. This is less complicated than using RSA-OAEP and treating RSA like a block cipher.

Comment: @SAIPeregrinus That generally doesn't work for practice assignments like above. You could of course create a key and then use a many-time pad or Caesar / Vigenere cipher or something similar - those only need a small key size and for the exercise the fact that they are completely insecure is not a problem.

Comment: Yeah, it's not what the exercise wants. But it's also safe, where what the exercise wants isn't. I think it's worth mentioning the "real world" way to use RSA for encryption (though RSA-OAEP is also common for hybrid schemes) even if it's not the exercise answer.

Comment: Still doesn't required -1.

Comment: After reading your suggestion @MaartenBodewes, I split up the numeric plaintext into digits and encrypted it, and upon decrypting, clubbed the decrypted digits. ALso, thank you for your responses SAI and Maarten